# Scaling and cross-validation in statistical models

Tags: machine-learning

Let's say i have a two dimensional dataset (X and Y variables). My goal is to fit a model that best describes the X-Y relationship Using a training subset of the dataset and then evaluate the performance using another test subset. and let's say i want to normalize/scale the Y vector to a vector with zero mean and standard deviation of 1. 
What is better and why? Scaling before partitioning, or the converse (do the scaling on the train partition and then the test partition separately)?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see any benefit to normalising the Y-vector. It will just add an extra layer to the relationship between X and Y.

Comment: @tomi i'm mainly doing the normalisation for another purpose. Gaussian process hyperparameters optimization renders more numerically stable results.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, ideally, you want to simulate the conditions of a real-world test set, to get the most accurate generalization error possible. Thus you should assume access to a test set in (1) only an online fashion (i.e., one input at a time only is available) and (2) only after training is complete.

Hence, you should compute the normalization parameters $P$ *on the training set*, and then apply this same normalization $P$ to both the training set *and* the test set.

Notice that this strategy is identical to that used by default for *batch normalization* in deep neural network libraries: namely, you learn the normalization parameters at training time, and then at test time you *freeze* the parameters and use them *as is* on test data.